# jQuery.ajax success function not executed in win xp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "students/login",
    data:{"data[Student][email]":_email,"data[Student][password]":_password},ss
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#confirm").text("");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    },
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == " success"){
            $("#confirm").text("Log in, please wait .......");
        } else {
            $("#confirm").text("No such user or password is incorrect!");
        }
    }
});
```

by the way,I do it with cakephp and jquery

Comment: Can you format the code a little bit for easier reading? ;) Also any other context, like what the browsers you tried; any javascript error hint, or it just didn't show up anything?

Comment: You still have some `ss` s behind your `data` assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that because of this? One extra space before the success, or just the format is wrong...

```
if(msg == " success")
```

Comment: But the question is can't be into the success: function

Comment: Which browser did you test, and how about other browsers you have under XP?

Answer (score 0):

You have **ss** right before **beforeSend:** Remove those and it should work. I found the error in one second after giving it a quick check on [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).